# MFC: what is the best way to generate and display large document?

Tags: mfc

I am still new to this area. My current project requires to generate and display large report (over a few hundred pages). The structure of document is quite simple but still contains row-column formatting with a few colors, fonts and lines. Also, it needs to be printable which is quite a headache. The approach I am taking is to use browser control plus HTML. One issue is that when the document gets big, UI is pretty lagging. Is there other way of doing that?

Comment: I'd simply not use a browser control.

Comment: I agree, is there other choices given the requirements? Thank you.